# Как занести сохранить в переменную текст который ввел пользователь telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

срочно нужна помощь, пыталась сама, ничего не получилось. Нужно чтобы после нажатия на определенную кнопку
бот предлагал пользователю ввести сообщение, а затем сохраняет ее в переменную.
(Библиотека telebot)
Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'q':
       msg = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Введите текст')
       bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, q_2)


def q_2(message):
    print(message.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо x ваша переменная

```
x = message.text
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]