# telegram-bot: как брать данные от пользователя?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Мне нужно, что бы бот помещал мои ответы в переменные.

Например:

**Бот:** *введите первое число*

**Юзер:** *1*

**Бот:** *введите второе число*

**Юзер:** *4*

И записывал первое и второе число как переменные, например, `a` и `b`.

Comment: Доброго времени суток. Ваш вопрос не попадает в тематику сообщества. Здесь решают проблемы, а не задачи. Что у вас не получается? Что пробовали?

Comment: Здравствуйте, Да в этом и сложность, что я просто напросто не знаю как это сделать, а именно взять число(в примере например 4) за переменную.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1207894/234134 `callback_query_handler`, `callback_inline(call)` замените на `content_type` и `func(message)` соответственно